# React Context without nesting a provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm wondering if it's possible to create a context and consume it without passing the context down the whole section of the dom tree.

To that extent I've created the following example:

`./components/count-context.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
const CountContext = React.createContext({count : 0} )


const CountContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  
  const incrementCount = () => {
    console.log("increment count", count)
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const decrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count - 1);
  }

  return (
    <CountContext.Provider value={{ count, setCount, incrementCount, decrementCount }}>
      {props.children}
    </CountContext.Provider>
  );
}

const CountDisplayNoProvider = (props) => {
  const { count } = React.useContext(CountContext)
  return (
      <p>{count}</p>
  )
}

const CountDisplaySelfProvided = (props) => {
  const { count } = React.useContext(CountContext)
  return (
    <CountContextProvider>
      <p>{count}</p>
    </CountContextProvider>
  )
}

const IncrementCountButton = (props) => {
  const { count, incrementCount, setCount } = React.useContext(CountContext)
  console.log(`count is a `, typeof(count))
  console.log(`incrementCount is a `, typeof(incrementCount))
  console.log(`setCount is a `, typeof(setCount))
  return (
    <button onClick={incrementCount}>IncrementCountButton</button>
  )
}
 

export {
  CountContextProvider,
  CountDisplayNoProvider,
  CountDisplaySelfProvided,
  IncrementCountButton
}
```

And: `./App.js`

```
import './App.css';

import { CountContextProvider, CountDisplaySelfProvided, CountDisplayNoProvider, IncrementCountButton} from './components/count-context'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>NO CONTEXT</p>
        CountDisplayNoProvider: <CountDisplayNoProvider />
        <IncrementCountButton />

        <br />

        CountDisplaySelfProvided: <CountDisplaySelfProvided />
        <IncrementCountButton />

      <CountContextProvider>
        <p>CountDisplayNoProvider inside CountContextProvider</p>
        <CountDisplayNoProvider />
        <IncrementCountButton />
      </CountContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The funny thing is that the CountDisplayNoProvider and CountDisplaySelfProvided both show a number: 0

but
count-context.js:34 incrementCount is a  undefined
count-context.js:35 setCount is a  undefined

--- so why is it that the count gets passed to NO CONTEXT, but not the functions?

And even stranger, why is it that I can't put the provider in the count's own component? (`CountDisplaySelfProvided`)

Thank you!!

Screenshot of the rendered output after rage clicking all the buttons
[image: Screenshot of the rendered output after rage clicking all the butt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand as to why those other components did get some value like 0 from the context. While we do need the provider to consume the values, different things happen to the other components.

**First CountDisplayNoProvider**

This only consumes the initial value of count which you've provided when creating the Context. `const CountContext = React.createContext({count : 0})`. However, if you've tried consuming the other functions you've passed on the Provider, then it would only return undefined because of it not being set initially when the context was created.

**CountDisplaySelfProvided**

This explains the same thing with the First `<CountDisplayNoProvider/>`. The problem with this one is you're already using the Context then providing it inside the return.

In this case, you're consuming it before you get everything from the
Provider. So you wouldn't be able to use the functions here too. While you did add a Provider, `useContext` runs first thus the undefined functions.

If it had children who would later consume it via useContext, then it should definitely work and have their own count, setCount & everything else you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

The first two incrementCountButtons did not work as it can not get CountContext.They are outside CountContextProvider now, you probably want to move it inside the CounterContextCounter

```
<div className="App">
    <CountContextProvider>    // Move CounterContextProvider here
      <p>NO CONTEXT</p>
        CountDisplayNoProvider: <CountDisplayNoProvider />
        <IncrementCountButton />
        <br />
        CountDisplaySelfProvided: <CountDisplaySelfProvided />
        <IncrementCountButton />
        <p>CountDisplayNoProvider inside CountContextProvider</p>
        <CountDisplayNoProvider />
        <IncrementCountButton />
    </CountContextProvider>    // end of counter context provider
 </div>
```